# Algorithm to change speech pitch

Tags: audio, speech, pitch

I'm looking for a way to heighten the pitch of recorded speech audio.

I'd like to change the pitch only at the end of the speech, to create a sort of "up speak".

What are the typical algorithms to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[PSOLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSOLA) (Pitch Synchronous Overlap and Add) is a digital signal processing technique used for speech processing and more specifically speech synthesis. It can be used to modify the pitch and duration of a speech signal.

Example code is 
https://github.com/joaocarvalhoopen/Pitch_Shifter_using_PSOLA_algorithm